# Rebalancing an AVL Tree

Tags: avl-tree

I have the following AVL tree:

```
                               10
                             /    \
                            5     12
                           / \   /  \
                          2  8   11  13
                        /  \ /\   
                        1  4 7 9
```

If I insert 3 then I get:

```
                               10
                             /    \
                            5     12
                           / \   /  \
                          2  8   11  13
                        /  \ /\   
                        1  4 7 9
                          /
                         3
```

If I calculate the Balance Factor for each node it seems that every BF is valid:
(Node:BF) -> 10:1, 5:0, 2:-1, 1:0, 4:-1, 8:0, 7:0, 9:0, 3:0, 12:0, 11:0, 13:0
But apparently this tree needs to be rebalanced. Where is there an invalid BF and then how would go about making the necessary rotations.

Comment: How are you determining these balance factors? It seems to me like you're doing that wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 should have a balance factor of 2 with it's left subtree 5-2-4-3 and its right subtree 12-13. A valid tree after a single rotation might look like 5 | 2 10 | 1 4 8 12 | nil nil 3 nil 7 9 11 13.

A possible method for rebalancing is the cut-link-algorithm: 
1. Name the unbalanced node z, one of it's child y and one of its child's child x.
2. Rename the nodes to a, b, c in inorder-traversal and let their children be T0, T1, T2 and T3 from left to right.
3. Set b as the new root, a as its left child and c as its right child. 
4. Append the four subtrees corresponding from left to right as T0, T1, T2 and T3.

Comment: I understand how I miscalculated the balance factor but I'm a little confused by the cut-link algorithm. When I rename the nodes to a,b,c in order transversal that would be: a-5, b-10, c-12. So then 10 would still be the root?

Comment: So z = 10 because 10 is the unbalanced node. Following the path to the inserted node we determine y = 5 and x = 2. The residual subtrees are T0 = 1, T1 = 4 | 3, T2 = 8 | 7 9 and T3 = 12 | 11 13. We then traverse x, y and z inorder. So a = x, b = y, c = z. We set b as the new root of the subtree which is 5. 2 is the root of the left and 5 the root of the right subtree. After appending T0, T1, T2 and T3 we get the tree from above as the result.
By the way: I should have mentioned that it is necessary to follow the path to the inserted node when determining x, y and z at 1.